# How to save image to disk with with gdal_translate?

Tags: python, gdal

I do:

```
import os
from gdal import *

filename = 'c:/rast.jpg'
outputTif = 'c:/rastOut.tif'
os.system('gdal_translate filename outputTif')
```

but it returns "1".

gdal_translate doesn't save the image to disk. Is any additional parameter needed?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean something like os.system('gdal_translate ' + filename + ' ' + outputTif)? You are using literal 'filename' and 'outputTif', not the values of those variables.

Comment: 'it' returned 1 because os.system() encounter an error. If the command would be succefully completed you'd get a '0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to describe GTiff driver and you do use string instead variable. Code below should work.

```
import os
from gdal import *

filename = 'c:/rast.jpg'
outputTif = 'c:/rastOut.tif'
os.system('gdal_translate -of GTiff %s %s'%(filename, outputTif))
```

Comment: Geotiff is the default output type. It doesn't need to be specified. The rest of your answer is correct though. The problem is the OPs use of literal strings instead of the variables.